# ProgressBar in AsyncTask is showing values more 100

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, android-progressbar

I am using `ProgressBar` with values to display during the extraction of database in my **Android** app but the `ProgressBar` values exceeds 100 and displays till **122%**

I tried setting,

```
if(progress<=100)
publishProgress(progress);
```

but this results in showing 100% for a long time.

Can anyone please help in the **calculation of progress** with responding to **file size** and **extraction**.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    String name = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("doInBackground");
        listener.onDoInBackground(context,true);
        name = "db_sqlite.7z";
        //InputStream of the sqlite file
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.db_sqlite);
        int fileSize = in.available();
        FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput("db.sqlite", 0);//Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {

         /*  In contrast to other classes in org.tukaani.xz,
             LZMAInputStream doesn't do buffering internally
             and reads one byte at a time. BufferedInputStream
             gives a huge performance improvement here but even
             then it's slower than the other input streams from
             org.tukaani.xz.
            in = new BufferedInputStream(in);   */

            in = new XZInputStream(in);
            int size;
            int counter=0;
            while ((size = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                //System.out.write(buf, 0, size);
                if(this.isCancelled())
                    break;
                out.write(buf, 0, size);
                counter++;
                progress = (int) (counter*100*1024/(double)fileSize);
                publishProgress(progress);
            }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    //System.out.println("onProgressUpdate");
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    listener.onProgressUpdation(context, true, values);
    }
```

In an activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdation(Context context, Boolean isStarted, Integer... values) {
                              tv_you_can_change.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.extracting_database) + "  " + values[0] + "%");
    tv_you_can_change.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    //System.out.println("onProgressUpdation");
    }
```

Comment: check the value of `values[0]` before setting the value to progress bar. i.e., before `.setProgress(values[0])`

Comment: @govindpatel: the problem is with the                 progress = (int) (counter*100*1024/(double)fileSize);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I found the way !

```
//Original file size i.e size after extraction
float fileSize = 160088064;
```

Hardcoded the file size after extraction...

```
try {
            // In contrast to other classes in org.tukaani.xz,
            // LZMAInputStream doesn't do buffering internally
            // and reads one byte at a time. BufferedInputStream
            // gives a huge performance improvement here but even
            // then it's slower than the other input streams from
            // org.tukaani.xz.
            //in = new BufferedInputStream(in);

            in = new XZInputStream(in);
            int size;
            int counter=0;
            while ((size = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                if(this.isCancelled())
                    break;
                out.write(buf, 0, size);
                counter++;
                //System.out.println((counter*8192)/fileSize);
                progress = (int) (((counter*bufferSize)/fileSize)*100);
                    publishProgress(progress);
            }
```

Thanks to everyone helped to find this out...

Answer (score 1):

InputStream.available() does not return the total number of bytes, it returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read without blocking.

There is no really good way to determine the total size in this situation. However, since it's a resource, you know the size at compile-time, and it doesn't change at runtime. So, just store the size in a Number resource (or hard-code it if you must).

For determining the number of bytes read, keep a running total of the number returned by in.read()
Then, progress is simply bytesRead/fileSize.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        String name = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("doInBackground");
            listener.onDoInBackground(context,true);
            name = "db_sqlite.7z";
        //InputStream of the sqlite file


 InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.db_sqlite);
    int fileSize = in.available();
    FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput("db.sqlite", 0);//Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    try {

     /*  In contrast to other classes in org.tukaani.xz,
         LZMAInputStream doesn't do buffering internally
         and reads one byte at a time. BufferedInputStream
         gives a huge performance improvement here but even
         then it's slower than the other input streams from
         org.tukaani.xz.
        in = new BufferedInputStream(in);   */

        in = new XZInputStream(in);
        int size;
        int counter=0;
        while ((size = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                //System.out.write(buf, 0, size);


  if(this.isCancelled())
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, size);
            counter++;

            progress = (int) (counter/(double)fileSize*100);
            publishProgress(progress);
        }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    //System.out.println("onProgressUpdate");


     super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        listener.onProgressUpdation(context, true, values);
        }
```

Comment: Tried this way its not showing any values, 0% remains still the extraction gets over.